# ICU Syntax Warning: The plural part specified below is overridden by a later plural part

Tags: flutter, build, localization

I've been working on a Flutter web project for about 5 months now, but I didn't start by using the iOS simulator (I worked with Chrome). Now, I've tried to run it on the iOS simulator and I'm encountering the following error when I attempt to do so.

```
"sq": 8 untranslated message(s).
"sr": 8 untranslated message(s).
"sr_Latn": 8 untranslated message(s).
"sv": 8 untranslated message(s).
"sw": 8 untranslated message(s).
"ta": 8 untranslated message(s).
"te": 8 untranslated message(s).
"th": 8 untranslated message(s).
"tl": 8 untranslated message(s).
"tr": 8 untranslated message(s).
"uk": 8 untranslated message(s).
"ur": 8 untranslated message(s).
"uz": 8 untranslated message(s).
"vi": 8 untranslated message(s).
"zh": 8 untranslated message(s).
"zh_CN": 8 untranslated message(s).
"zh_HK": 8 untranslated message(s).
"zh_TW": 8 untranslated message(s).
"zu": 8 untranslated message(s).
To see a detailed report, use the untranslated-messages-file
option in the l10n.yaml file:
untranslated-messages-file: desiredFileName.txt
<other option>: <other selection>


This will generate a JSON format file containing all messages that
need to be translated.
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                           1,716ms
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           36.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): [intl_am.arb:rallyAlertsMessageUnassignedTransactions] ICU Syntax Warning: The plural part specified below is overridden by a later plural part.


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: seems like im the only one who got this error 

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:add this line in your l10.yaml file
`untranslated-messages-file: untranslatedmessage.txt`

after adding this, if you run your code, it will generate a new file named untranslatedmessage.txt. In that file you can see the list of mismatched keys (the keys which are not translated) . You can correct that keys and run the code .

I got the same error while using translation in flutter..
The mistake I made was : The variable name was different in the two translation files.
example: while translating "time line", - in the english arb file I have given "timeLine" while in the tamil arb file I have given "timeline".
Because of this the tamil translation was not properly done.
you can double check the names for any mistake made.